# "Trying to get property of non-object" for image_get_info

Tags: media

I have the following code:

```
  $imageinfo = image_get_info($newfile->uri, $toolkit = FALSE);

  $newrecord = array(
     blah blah blah
     'width' => $imageinfo->width,
     'height' => $imageinfo->height
    );
```

The width and height lines get the "Trying to get property of non-object" error.

If I print the contents of the `$imageinfo` array, it's this:

```
Array  
(  
    [width] => 630  
    [height] => 315  
    [extension] => jpg  
    [mime_type] => image/jpeg  
    [file_size] => 30334  
)
```

I must be doing something stupid here.  What is it?

Comment: Hello. This is general PHP question, really. Arrays are not objects and objects are not arrays, it's that simple :) Use array syntax for arrays. `$imageinfo['width']` for example.

Comment: Sorry, I had a complete brain fart. Apologies for taking up everybody's time.

Comment: As side note, you simply use `$imageinfo = image_get_info($newfile->uri);`. PHP doesn't have keyword arguments like Python. Your code is setting `$toolkit` to `FALSE`, and passing `FALSE` as function parameter; since you are not otherwise using `$toolkit`, setting it is useless.

Answer (score 1):

Always, always read the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!image.inc/function/image_get_info/7) first:

> **Return Value**
>
> FALSE, if the file could not be found or is not an image. Otherwise, **a keyed array** containing information about the image:

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Seems to me OP already knows it's an array, but is lost about what do to with this fact.

Comment: @Mołot Indeed. This was the only Drupal-way I could think to answer the question :)